# How to split a text value to get json for each sub text in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, database, api, codeigniter

I have two databases of `fleet_registration` that contain information about buses and booking.In buses database i have seat numbers named as A1,A2,A3,A4,A5... in single text column depending on number of seats in that bus (I attached image of database showing bus info).Also in another table of `tkt_booking` i have list of booked seats but a single as one seat.

I need to retrieve json of booked seats from `tkt_booking` as well as unbooked seats from `fleet_registration`with information as those of booked seats even null..

```
    public function choose_seat($data) 
    {
    $timetableId = $data['timetableId'];
    $query = $this->db->select("tb.seat_numbers AS seat_label,
    tb.id_no AS ticket_number,
    tb.payment_status,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', tp.firstname, tp.lastname) AS passenger_name, 
        tb.agent_id,tb.booking_type

            ")
               ->from('tkt_booking AS tb')
               ->join('tkt_passenger AS tp', 'tb.tkt_passenger_id_no = tp.id_no' ,'full')
               ->join('trip_assign AS ta', 'tb.trip_id_no = ta.id' ,'full')
           ->where('ta.id_no', $timetableId)
           ->get()
           ->result();      
    if($query){
          return $query;

        }else{
      return 0;
      }
}
```

On above codes i searched all list of booked seats and the following is a result

```
    {
    "seats": [
        {
            "seat_label": "A1",
            "ticket_number": "TYTYTY",
            "payment_status": "booking",
            "passenger_name": "jaffary yusuph",
            "agent_id": "2",
            "booking_type": "ilu"
        }
    ]
}
```

It only display single seat that is booked.I have not even write single piece of line to fetch info for non booked seat.That is my problem i need help to retrieve all information of booked and non booked seats at single json.

My databases

[image: tkt_booking]

[image: fleet_registration]

[image: trip_assign]

Comment: I think you want something like this, $query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}

This function returns the query result as a pure array

Comment: this kindof issue is **exactly** why you **don't** want to store "serialized" inputs in the database.

Comment: @Alex can you help me please..